# Vanity URL not obviously discoverable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I know my Careers vanity URL is `/pekka` because I vaguely remember picking that once.

I see no way to discover it in the actual careers profile, though.

That should probably be fixed.

**Edit:** ahh, it's in "privacy settings".

It should be more prominent, I met somebody the other day who didn't know the feature existed.

How about putting it in the top of the bar to the right, or place it in a separate menu item labelled "Public URL" or so?

Answer (score 5):

This has come up before, and we are going to make it more discoverable.  For a while we tabled it while we looked at larger profile design issues, but it's easy enough to fix and a large enough oversight on our part that we'll slip it in quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to your profile, and then click on privacy settings, you can set/view/change your vanity URL.

[image]

Comment: I did find that, but it should arguably be more easy to find.